# How to override LAZY loading after session was closed?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I work with hibernate and try to optimize loading foreign entities annotated with

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

I don't want to retrieve foreign entity during hibernate query and use LAZY fetch type.
Later(after session already closed), I want to get that foreign entity but use tool that different from hibernate (another cached DAO (GuavaCache) that already stores foreign entity).

Of couse, immediately I have got an LazyInitializationException.

I can't replace @ManyToOne annotation with @Transient because of toooooo much legacy HQL code witch does not works after deleting @MabyToOne.

Somewere somebody adviced to make getter method **final** and do not access to entity **field** straightly, but just use getter. Here is an example :

```
    private int foreignId;

@Basic
@Column(name = "foregn_id")
public int getForeignId() { return foreignId;}
public void setForeignId(int id) { this.foreignId = id; }


// private DBForeignEntity foreignEntity;  no more sense to have this field

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "foregn_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public final DBForeignEntity getForeign() {
    // return foreignEntity; deprecated usage! Hibernate will create proxy object and throw LazyInitException after session was closed
    return getFromCache(getForeignId());
}

public void setForeign(DBForeignEntity foreignEntity) {
    // this.foreignEntity = foreignEntity;   no more sence for having setter at all
}
```

this ugly solution exludes any abilities to persist nested entities, because of no setter for foreign entity anymore!

Is there another solution to deprecate Hibernate to create a proxy object for my entity? 
How to avoid LazyInitializationException if session was closed?
Is there any bad consequences of non-proxing in this case?

Comment: So basically when fetching associated entity, you don't want to use same session-factory, you are referring to another data store (maybe same, but via different mechanism-guava). If that is the case, then I think you would have to make the association between primary and associated entity manually. Not exactly sure about problem, so writing it as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: What does it mean? "...make the association between primary and associated entity manually" How it must look like?

Comment: It means, that you will have to fetch asociations by yourself and bind them to proper fields manually.

Comment: But hibernate still load asociations by himself. It is not necessary
and makes more queries to data base

Comment: @user2602807 that understanding is somewhat incorrect. Even when it is lazy, when you want to access the associated entities, hibernate has to make a db call. But it does so only if the primary entity is in a managed state. Lazy means those are loaded; only lazily - that is, when actually required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current situation hibernate proxies only child (foreignEntity) entity, and do not proxy current (parent) entity. Thus, there is no problem to check the instance of foreign entity and replace it with custom loaded :

```
private int foreignId;

@Basic
@Column(name = "foregn_id")
public int getForeignId() { return foreignId;}
public void setForeignId(int id) { this.foreignId = id; }

private DBForeignEntity foreignEntity;  

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "foregn_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public final DBForeignEntity getForeignEntity() {
    if (foreignEntity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        foreignEntity = getFromCache(foreignId);
    }
    return foreignEntity;
}

public void setForeign(DBForeignEntity foreignEntity) {
    this.foreignEntity = foreignEntity;   
}
```

Further, there is no LazyInitException during invoking

```
DBParentEntity.getForeignEntity()
```